# Passing a list of dictionaries to a function that accepts a json file

Tags: python, json, io

I have a list of dictionaries that I want to pass into a function that accepts a json file.

My current approach is to (1) convert the list of dicts to json using `json.dumps()` and (2) passing it as an argument via `StringIO()`

I getting the error.  `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

I'm not sure how to go about solving this or even if I using the right approach.  Any help is appreciated.

Edit:

An example of the code

```
import tdclient as td
import json
from io import StringIO

l = [{'a': 1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
l_json = json.dumps(l)

with td.Client(TD_APIKEY) as con:
    con.import_file('test', 'temp', 'json', StringIO(l_json))
```

and the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-d81f043acd58> in <module>()
      7 
      8 with td.Client(TD_APIKEY) as con:
----> 9     con.import_file('test', 'temp', 'json', StringIO(l_json))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tdclient/client.py in import_file(self, db_name, table_name, format, file, unique_id)
    605         Returns: float represents the elapsed time to import data
    606         """
--> 607         return self.api.import_file(db_name, table_name, format, file, unique_id=unique_id)
    608 
    609     def results(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tdclient/import_api.py in import_file(self, db, table, format, file, unique_id, **kwargs)
     61         Returns: float represents the elapsed time to import data
     62         """
---> 63         with contextlib.closing(self._prepare_file(file, format, **kwargs)) as fp:
     64             size = os.fstat(fp.fileno()).st_size
     65             return self.import_data(db, table, "msgpack.gz", fp, size, unique_id=unique_id)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tdclient/api.py in _prepare_file(self, file_like, fmt, **kwargs)
    426             packer = msgpack.Packer()
    427             with contextlib.closing(self._read_file(file_like, fmt, **kwargs)) as items:
--> 428                 for item in items:
    429                     try:
    430                         mp = packer.pack(item)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tdclient/api.py in _read_json_file(self, file_like, **kwargs)
    471         # current impl doesn't torelate any JSON parse error
    472         for s in file_like:
--> 473             record = json.loads(s.decode("utf-8"))
    474             self._validate_record(record)
    475             yield record

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Would you please show us your code and some example data?

Comment: The solution is to stop trying to call the `decode` method on a string. If you need a more detailed answer, you have to provide a more detailed question - a [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, I've added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import_file is expecting BytesIO rather than StringIO (see their [test](https://github.com/treasure-data/td-client-python/blob/bf8b8b550fd9e11afa88969f69c462b6f8739a5b/tdclient/test/import_api_test.py))

Try this

```
import tdclient as td
import json
from io import BytesIO

l = [{'a': 1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]
l_json = json.dumps(l)

with td.Client(2) as con:
    con.import_file('test', 'temp', 'json', BytesIO(bytes(l_json, 'utf-8')))
```

We are encoding to just let it decode but it should work. I don't have an API Key to verify further, but I got past the error you mentioned.